# Stripe - How to add cardholder name and zip code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, stripe-payments

I'm working on a Stripe API integration and have a simple model that works. I would like to add two more fields for users to fill out, the card holder name and the billing zip code for each transaction. The Stipe token, email address, amount and record_id are all being passed to Stripe's site for validation, and that information is also being sent back to the PHP processing script. Does anyone know what Stripe uses for both the cardholder's name and the zip code? These are options that can be added, but I can't find Stripe's naming convention for these.

### HTML

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<div class=“container”>
  <form>
    <input type="text" onclick="getPrice()" value="Click for Price" />
    <!-- This grabs the price determined by a PHP backend process -->
  </form>
  <br />
  <br />
  <form id="myForm" action="charge.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeToken" name="stripeToken" />
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeEmail" name="stripeEmail" />
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeZipcode" name="stripeZipcode" />
    <input type="hidden" id="cardHolder" name="cardHolder" />
    <input type="hidden" id="amountInCents" name="amountInCents" />
    <input type="hidden" id="record_id" name="record_id" />
  </form>

  <input type="button" id="customButton" value="Pay" placeholder="$10.00">
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```js
// Get Price Function
function getPrice() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // CREATE THE myPromo VAR AND USE promoDct VAR WITH INNERHTML FOR OUTPUT
      var myPrice = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

      // Create a variable to hold the error message
      var errorMes = myPrice.errorMes;
      var price = myPrice.price;

      // Use a switch statement to output proper info
      switch (errorMes) {
        case 'Error':
          window.alert('Something went wrong.');
          break;
        case 'No error':
          // set the value of the PHP derived charge to JS var
          window.charge = price;
          break;
      }
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "get_price.php", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xmlhttp.send('string');
}

// Stripe API Function

// Convert PHP Instance ID to JS var
var recordNum = "<?php echo $record_id; ?>";

var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_6fFZO2AWrKR8NqFslGt2POfsahKN5jZg0e',
  token: function(token) {
    $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
    $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
    $("#stripeZipcode").val(token.zipCode);
    $("#stripeHolder").val(token.cardHolder);
    $("#amountInCents").val(window.charge);
    $("#record_id").val(recordNum);
    $("#myForm").submit();
  }
});

$('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
  var amountInCents = Math.floor($("#amountInDollars").val() * 100);
  var displayAmount = parseFloat(window.charge / 100);
  // Open Checkout with further options
  handler.open({
    name: 'Travelers Free Classifieds',
    description: 'Custom amount ($' + displayAmount + ')',
    amount: window.charge,
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});
```

### PHP

```php
// BACK END Charge the user's card:
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
  'description' => $_SESSION['record_id'],
  'amount'   => $amount,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'source' => $token,
]);
```

Any help with this will be most appreciated!

Cheers,
Rick

Comment: where are you trying to pass `name` and `zip`? On the Charge or on the Token? Also looks like you're using legacy Checkout (the modal) which is deprecated and ideally you should be using Stripe Elements or new Stripe Checkout over legacy Checkout.

Comment: Hello Polywhirl, Thanks for responding, I was trying pass the cardholder name and the zip code, but those fields come back as an empty string from Stripe.

Comment: sorry could you clarify more? Where are the fields empty? On the Token object you get back from Stripe?

Comment: Hello Hmunoz, Yes, that's correct. Everything else is sent back to the php processing page.

Comment: legacy Checkout doesn't support collecting `name`, only `zipcode`. You cannot modify the fields of Legacy Checkout either, you can just display limited fields. Since legacy Checkout is considered deprecated, I would say migrate to new Checkout, that automatically collects name and zip

Comment: Thank you hmunoz, that's a good reason that it's not working. Odd though, that they would have set that up in such a manner. cheers

Comment: legacy Checkout was only a tokenization modal without much customizability, and then it was overtaken by Stripe Elements which is more flexible than legacy Checkout. Finally, new Checkout is an easier integration than Elements but supports many things out of the box

Comment: Hi hmunoz, After my last response I started working with Elements, Just saw this comment, and will look at NEW checkout. I didn't know there was such a thing. thanks!